# R remove duplicate rows

Tags: r, unique

I have a dataframe where I would like to remove all rows with duplicates. For instance my dataframe looks like:

```
> df <- data.frame(A = c("Happy", "Happy", "Sad", "Confused", "Mad", "Mad"), B = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
> df
         A B
1    Happy 1
2    Happy 2
3      Sad 3
4 Confused 4
5      Mad 5
6      Mad 6
```

I only want rows where the entries in A are unique to get:

```
         A B
1      Sad 3
2 Confused 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `duplicated`

```
df[!(duplicated(df$A)|duplicated(df$A,fromLast=TRUE)),]
#         A B
#3      Sad 3
#4 Confused 4
```

or

```
df[df$A %in% with(as.data.frame(table(df$A)), Var1[Freq==1]),]
#       A B
#3      Sad 3
#4 Confused 4
```

or

```
df[colSums(sapply(df$A, `==`, df$A))==1,]
#         A B
#3      Sad 3
#4 Confused 4
```

or

```
df[colSums(Vectorize(function(x) x==df$A)(df$A))==1,]
```

or using `data.table` (similar to @beginneR's use of `ave`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.SD[.N==1], by=A] 
#          A B
#1:      Sad 3
#2: Confused 4
```

or

```
 setDT(df)[df[,.I[.N==1], by=A]$V1]
 #          A B
 #1:      Sad 3
 #2: Confused 4
```

Answer (score 5):

akrun seems to be collecting different methods, so here's another one in base:

```
df[ave(as.numeric(df$A), df$A, FUN = length) == 1,]
#         A B
#3      Sad 3
#4 Confused 4
```

(I guess the one with `duplicated` would be the most commonly used method)

Or using dplyr:

```
require(dplyr)
group_by(df, A) %>% filter(n() == 1)
```

Comment: I was waiting for the `dplyr` answer.  What took you so long? ;-)